# Radio buttons bound to knockout computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have some problems with knockoutjs writables computes observables I think.
I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fool/LkqTU/27579/).

What I need is actually not so hard:
I have the nullable `WeightInGramms` and `VolumeInMilliliters` values.
These values should be bound to two input fields (only one of them should be visible).
At the top, the user can choose which of these values he want to use with the radio buttons.

At initialisation, when both of them are null, the "g" radio button should be checked, also when `WeightInGramms` is not null. When `VolumeInMilliliters` have some value, the "ml" radio button should be checked.

I used a **knockoutjs writable computes observable** for this, please correct me if there is a better way to do this!

So, the read function seems to work, when I change the value in the input which are bind to `WeightInGramms` or `VolumeInMilliliters`. But when I change the radio buttons nothing happens...

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    this.VolumeInMilliliters = ko.observable(data.VolumeInMilliliters);
    this.WeightInGramms = ko.observable(data.WeightInGramms);

    this.GrammIsSelected = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return (!self.WeightInGramms() && !self.VolumeInMilliliters()) || !self.VolumeInMilliliters();
    },
        write: function (newValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
            return newValue;
        },
        owner: this
    });

};
```

When I change the radio buttons, the corresponding input field should be visible:

```
<div data-bind="visible: GrammIsSelected">g is active</div>
<div data-bind="visible: !GrammIsSelected()">ml is active</div>
```

Edit:
When the Form is loaded for the first Time both values will be null -> the "g" button should be checked.

The observables can be initialized with:

```
null, null  
33, null 
null, 33
```

Both can be null, but only one of them can have a value. 
If the user types in a value, and then clicks the other radio the value can be applied to the other value.

I hop it is a bit clearer

Comment: What do you really wanna do dude? Your code and your question is really unclear... Avoid the technical details this time, just in plain English, what is your UI supposed to do?

Comment: ok @AdrianSalazar, I updated the fiddle and the question. Maybee it is a bit clearer ... :-/

Comment: all right... much better... piece of cake!

Comment: Please, describe clearly the behavior: what happens when the form is loaded for the first time? how are the observables intialized? what happens if the user writes a value and then clicks the other radio? what hapens if the user types the other radio again and types values in both sides? You need to face this in a very different way: get the value an units, and no more than that, and everything willbe much more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `write` function doesn't *write* anything, it seems?

Contrary to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33499231/419956), based on my experience I'll give you the advice *not* to avoid writeable computeds: used wisely they can be very effective!

Note: in my answer I try to remain close to the original design from the question, but if you're able (have resources available) I recommend redesigning things even more based on [the answer by @Tyblitz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33506015/419956).

Here's the way you could approach this utilizing a computed:

```js
var ViewModel = function (data) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.VolumeInMilliliters = ko.observable(data.VolumeInMilliliters);
  self.WeightInGramms = ko.observable(data.WeightInGramms);

  var _measurementType = ko.observable("volume");

  self.MeasurementType = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      return _measurementType();
    },
    write: function (newValue) {
      _measurementType(newValue);
      self.VolumeInMilliliters(newValue === "volume" ? 0 : null);
      self.WeightInGramms(newValue === "mass" ? 0 : null);
    }
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel({ VolumeInMilliliters: 12 }));
```

```css
label { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="measurementType" value="volume" data-bind="checked: MeasurementType">
  Volume
</label>
<input data-bind="value: VolumeInMilliliters, enable: MeasurementType() === 'volume'">

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="measurementType" value="mass" data-bind="checked: MeasurementType">
  Weight in gramms
</label>
<input data-bind="value: WeightInGramms, enable: MeasurementType() === 'mass'">
```

Comment: Even if @Tyblitz answer might be the best one here, this answer solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

- Make your viewModel (JS) resemble the view (HTML) as much as possible. Additionally, this avoids having to repeat too much markup. In this case, radio buttons are always lists, and so it is most convenient to store the options in an array.
- Instead of testing whether `GrammIsselected`, you should define a `selected` observable that holds the selected metric. This way if you ever add more options, the code will still work without refactoring.
- When to use a computed property? A computed property adds **readonly** value by calculating a result based on multiple observables/ variables. A writeable computed property does the same, except you can **write back** changes. This makes it especially useful for 'Select all' style checkboxes (see [example 2 in the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html)), data validation & transformations.

The absolutely clearest setup for what you want to achieve would be the following:

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    this.metrics = [
        { name: 'g',  value: ko.observable(data.WeightInGramms) },
        { name: 'ml', value: ko.observable(data.VolumeInMilliliters) }
    ];
    this.selectedMetric = ko.observable(this.metrics[0]);
};
```

By setting an object as observable (`selectedMetric`), you can furthermore simplify the markup for the volume/weight input:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">choose</label>
    <div class="controls" data-bind="with: selectedMetric">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: value">
        <span class="help-inline" data-bind="text: '(' + name + ')'"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Getting the 'final value' of your app would be as easy as retrieving `selectedMetric().value()`.

A computed property isn't super useful here, but for example, if you wanted to provide a way for the user to both set the g/ml with radio buttons and text, you could add the following method to your viewModel:

```
this.selectedMetricByText = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return this.selectedMetric().name;
    },
    write: function(value) {
        var newMetric = ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.metrics, function(metric) {
            return metric.name === value;
        }) || false;
        this.selectedMetric(newMetric || this.metrics[0]);
    }
}, this);
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27584/)

Comment: This is great advice. It deviates from the original design in the question even more than I did, but for the better IMO. OP, if you're able to redesign things, pick this answer over my earlier suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For radio buttons, you need to use the "checked" binding.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

And for my personal experience (as a KO nija) I have to give you the advice: avoid writeable ko computed.

```
<input type="radio" name="unitSelector" value="g" data-bind="checked: unit" /> Grams</br>
<input type="radio" name="unitSelector" value="ml" data-bind="checked: unit" /> Millis</br>
```

Now the view model

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.unit = ko.observable('g');
    self.userValue = ko.observable(data.WeightInGramms);
};
```

Now the binding should only care about the value entered by the user, you don't need computed here and you don't need two fields...

```
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: userValue ">
<span data-bind="text: unit">  </span>
```

It looks really too simple but that's what you need, as @Jotabe mentioned, you should take measurement and the unit as two separate things... what you do with this thing later, could be done with computed observables.

If this thing doesn't solve your problem then you should tell what you really want...

Comment: okay, very thanks for this for now! Problem is, that the backend response gives me the data. So I think we have to change that...

Comment: *"I have to give you the advice: avoid writeable ko computed."* based on what experience/ bugs? I've never had trouble with them..

Comment: @Tybitz seriously? what do you want from me... can't/won't enter an annoying discussion based on a highly subjective matter...

Comment: Don't take it personally, @Tyblitz was just questioning part of the *post*. You've opened this door by adding an *opinionated* part in your answer. This is fine, but it's not uncommon for others to ask you to back up such a claim with examples. If you've add experience/bugs/examples to show that writeable computes cause problems it would improve your post, thus benefitting everyone involved.